# Ghost mysql process running even I stopped mysql running on boot

Tags: mysql, linux

This morning I get up to a date where all db on my dedicated server down. I couldn't restart the service. When I do `ps aux | grep mysql` I see a process which pid changes constantly.

> root      4715  0.0  0.0 103248   844 pts/0    S+   08:28   0:00 grep mysql

So I stop running on boot and restarted the server.

`chkconfig --list mysql` shows me

> mysql           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off

But I still see mysql process on ps. Why?

Server OS: CentOS.
Panel: WHM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is the `grep` process running. `mysql` is not running.

Answer (score 1):

The entry you're seeing is the command you are using to search for MySQL.

To test this try doing:

```
ps aux | grep banana
```